# How to call user define function in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a query in SQL server 2014

```
Declare @ff varchar(33)
set @ff='DAY'+cast((SELECT DAY('2011-04-02')) as varchar(2))
print @ff
update CUSTOMER set DAY1='p' where USERId=12
update CUSTOMER set @ff=''+'f'+'' where USERId=15
print @ff
select * from CUSTOMER
```

It gives the message that one row is effected but there is no change take place in my table. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: what is this supposed to do? `update CUSTOMER set @ff=''+'f'+'' where USERId=15` as you're updating the variable not the table?

Comment: If you perform normal select, this will also show: `{n} row(s) affected`. Are you sure you are getting this message for update?

Comment: What does this have to do with a user defined function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable for the column name in the way you do, so the second update needs to be done with a dynamic sql statement where you inject the variable into the query string like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'update CUSTOMER set ' + @ff + ' = ''f'' where USERId=15'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

With the variable `@ff` defined as:

```
Declare @ff nvarchar(33)
set @ff='DAY'+cast((SELECT DAY('2011-04-02')) as varchar(2))
```

This would update the column `DAY2` to have the value `f` for `userid = 15`

You could however get rid of the `@ff` variable and build the query string directly:

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT(N'update CUSTOMER set DAY', DAY('2011-04-02'), ' = ''f'' where USERId=15')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this SQL Server? The update will update the contents of the variable, not the column in a table. You cannot use variables to refer the name of the column. If you need to do a dynamic update like that, you'll have to use dynamic SQL with EXEC or sp_executesql.